# NodeMCU / ESP8266 died

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I created the attached circuit. It's about as simple as it gets, 4 buttons (2 low since GPIO pins are pulled up, and 2 high or low depending on whether they're pressed), a stepper motor controller, and a 12v power supply which powers the motor, but also the arduino by stepping down the voltage via a buck converter. Note I have connected all grounds together in the actual circuit.

It worked fine at first, but then the Node MCU / ESP8266 died. I swapped it and it worked fine again. Then the next day, dead again. I'm on a third one and everything seems to be working fine.

My question is have I got unlucky with a couple of defective boards, or is there something fundamentally wrong with my circuit that is killing the poor things?

[image]

Comment: why are LIM_1 and LIM_2 wired differently from MAN_1? ... they should really be wired same as MAN_1

Comment: @jsotola The 2 GPIOs they are hooked up to have a pull up resistor, so it just made sense

Comment: `hooked up` ... do you mean `configured in software`?

Comment: @jsotola I'm new to the board and just googled it and got [this](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/) website which has a table which specifically noted GPIO0 and GPIO2 have inputs pulled up. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the enquiry; does any of this affect anything related to my question or are we just being pedantic?

Comment: Is the LM2596 a single chip or full breakout board with the necessary inductor, capacitor, diode, etc. on it? What stepper motor part are you using?

Comment: @Polynomial it's a full breakout board, same for the stepper driver. I'm not sure on the stepper motor part, but it's one like you'd see on a 3D printer: "2 Phase Step Motor Bipolar 1.5A". I've adjusted the motor driver current limiter accordingly. Let me know if there is any better info needed and I can try and dig it up

Comment: @Matthew, when you say that the MCU was dead, could you give more details of what happens? For eg., does some pin get shorted, are you able to program the MCU?, is it drawing too much current? From the symptom of the problem, it will be clear which area we need to focus on debugging

Comment: @sai one board completely dead, doesn't seem to power on or connect to the computer via usb. Another one seems fine, can transfer programs to it via PC, but doesn't work, not even a simple LED flashing program (although the LED does flash to indicate the program is uploading, so it's not just a dead LED). Note for both of these I'm disconnecting them completely from the above circuit and they still behave the same.
Third board works perfectly fine in the circuit. I guess I'm here to make sure in principle the above circuit is fine and isn't responsible for killing the other two. Thanks

Comment: If I am not mistaken, A4988 Logic high is 5V whereas the IO logic high of NODE MCU IOs is 3.3V. Can you check? In that case, you'd need level shifters isn't it?

Comment: Do please add links to the schematics of the breakout boards also in the question. For eg., I see the inputs RST & SLP are both shorted. Is there an internal pullup on the A4988 board that sets them high?

Comment: @sai I don't understand the line of enquiry you're pursuing here; the logic levels are triggering just fine, and yes, RST and SLP are tied together because they are active low and one of them has an internal pull down (I forget which). Correct me if I'm wrong, but surely none of this could or would lead to boards dying.

Comment: @MatthewShaile, logic level mismatch can cause a board to work initially and stop working later because it is fundamentally flawed design but it will not damage the nodemcu because I don't see any outputs from A4988 going to the nodemcu.